# Screen-Lock Breaks Uploads

Tags: ios, network, data-transfer, screen-lock, ipados

I've noticed that when uploading long-ish videos to social media, if the device goes to autolock, invariably I'll see the upload failed. Not a problem if one is continuously using the device so screen-lock doesn't activate, but if the file is taking over an hour...

How can I stop screen-lock from breaking my uploads?

Comment: It's up to the app developer to enable 'no lock whilst in use'. Sat navs all do that, otherwise they'd be pretty pointless in-car. I also have a book reader which has the option as a user pref.

Comment: @Tetsujin Much obliged- I checked in app settings, but found no where I could modify the behaviour to stop killing my uploads.  However, it's still counter-intuitive to just kill active connections because Screen-Lock activates.  Thanks for the insight on how the gears turn under the hood!

Comment: Welcome. I presume [I'm not a developer, btw] that the app designer needs to balance the needs of their average user against convenience for the expert/power user. Putting a lock switch in would let them satisfy both needs. I'd see if the developer has some kind of feedback system you could report it to them for future consideration. I think some apps can toggle behaviour depending on whether the phone is plugged in or on battery. That might be worth investigating too.

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE:

Adding feedback from @Tetsujin:

Apparently the developer of the app themselves can disable Screen-lock from activating while there's on-going activity. However, if they don't, the following is a hack to stop Screen-Lock from activating and busting your uploads.

In "***Settings***,":

"***Display & Brightness***" > "***Auto-Lock***" and choose "***Never***"

Don't forget to restore the previous value to something more reasonable after your upload completes or you'll run your battery flat quickly.

It's a bit counter-intuitive that just because screen-lock kicks-in, your connections should all break.  If we say Screen-Lock is to stop an unattended phone being abused, it doesn't necessarily follow that you want all your uploads to be killed...